# EF5 Code First: Newly created entities' related entities are not lazy loaded although a proxy is used

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, code-first, poco

consider the following snippet:

```
// this.ctx is an instance of our EF Code First DB Context.
// the entity in this example is called "Something", and the DB set "Somethings".
// there is also another entity type called "SomethingElse".
// the Something entity is declared like this:
// 
// public class Something {
//   public int Foo { get; set; }
//   public string Bar { get; set; }
// 
//   public virtual IList<SomethingElse> RelatedStuff { get; set; }
// }
// 

// Create is used to ensure a proxy is created.    
var something = this.ctx.Somethings.Create();

// The new entity is added
this.ctx.Somethings.Add(something);    

// lazy loading: ON
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(this.ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled);    

// the entity is really in "added" state
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(this.ctx.Entry(something).State == EntityState.Added);

// *** lazy loading does not work! ***
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(something.RelatedStuff == null);

// note: if stepping through this with the debugger, I can confirm that "something" is
//       of the DynamicProxy type, not a plain "Something" POCO.

// but, if we change the state manually...
this.ctx.Entry(something).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

// *** it works!! ***    (doing a this.ctx.SaveChanges(), actually, also makes this work)
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(something.RelatedStuff!= null);
```

Can someone explain to me why the lazy loading on the newly created POCO is not working, although lazy loading is ON and the property is virtual, and when changing the state, is magically starts to work? If I'm not mistaken, even for transient objects, lazy loading should work, shouldn't it??

Cheers,
   Tim

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in entity framework 5 lazy loading feature is disabled by default, 
I found nothing useful on web but just figured out my problem with setting this feature explicitly in code, after defining "DbContext" object  :

```
protected DbContext Context;
protected IDbSet<T> DbSet;

public Repository(DbContext context)
{
     Context = context;
     DbSet = Context.Set<T>();

     Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, Lazy Loading indeed is enabled in my test case.